# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get', and the knn step is right

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, compiler-errors, knn

> I have a problem with the get() method its not being recognized. I have not found a solution. I want to take the input from the GUI and apply it to the knn algorithm

---

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

from tkinter import * 
top = Tk('300','300')
box= Text(top).grid(row=1,column=1)
p = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, stop_words='english')
p.fit(box.get("1.0",END))
wordOfp = p.transform(p)

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(wordOfp,y,random_state = 42, test_size = 0.2)# y is target
model = OneVsRestClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, metric= 'euclidean'  ))
model.fit(x_train,y_train)
prediction = model.predict(x_test)
```

---

this is a error
p.fit(box.get("1.0",END))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 0):

You need to split `box` onto two lines:

```
box= Text(top)
box.grid(row=1,column=1)
p.fit(box.get("1.0",END))
```

You cannot use the grid function on the same line as your entrypoint otherwise it will return None. This answer has a better explanation if needed:

[Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Also you will get an error because `END` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate Text declaration and grid in order it to work.
try this.

```
box= Text(top)
box.grid(row=1,column=1)
```